# Maximal Accretive Implies Injective

Tags: spectral-theory

I'm having trouble proving that $B $ is essentielly maximal accretive implies that there  existes $ a>0 $ such that  $(A^∗+a Id)$ is injective.

where B is the closure of the operator A and A* is the adjoint of A

Here is what i did:

we proceede by contraposition. let us suppose that for any  $a>0$ we have $(A^∗+a Id)$ is not injective hence there exists $u∈D(A^∗)$ such that $A^∗u=−au$ hence $<A^∗u,u>=−a||u||^2 $ or $<A^∗u,u>=<B^∗u,u>$ 
but I could not conclude.

Comment: there is no one who can help?

Comment: Please, try to make the titles of your questions more informative. E.g., *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.*
From [How can I ask a good question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: I tried editing your question to use the correct words, fix formatting, etc. please let me know if I made an important mistake

Comment: Also, I can't help because I don't know what essentially maximal accretive means, and Google isn't being very useful

Comment: Hi Stella Biderman  ,thanks for edditing the title.for the definition:Let A be an operator  in a Hilbert space  H with  domain D(A). 
we say that  A is essentielly maximal accretif if it is accretif( $Re<Au,u> \ge 0$) and if it  admets a unique maximal accretive  extension .
Remarck :an operator is said maximal accretif if it is  accretif and if it doesn't admet any proper  accretive extension

Comment: here is the proposition that i am trying to prove(page 8-9):http://cermics.enpc.fr/~stoltz/MATHERIALS/nier1.pdf

Comment: Okay, but what does accretive mean? And what is a maximal accretive extension!

Comment: A is said accretif if ∀ψ ∈ D(A), Re <ψ , Aψ> ≥ 0

Comment: A is said  maximal accretive if it doesn't admit any proper accretive extension

Comment: there is no idea?